# Where can in get the location of java interprater on termux so that i can manually select the interprater for vs code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, termux

I am trying to use java on termux via vscode but vscode isn't able to locate java jdk by itself. So what is the problem there. I am trying to locate java interprater on my termux directories at `/home/home/com.termux/files/usr/lib` but I am not able to find java interprater. Someone tell me where is the java interprater is located. java is working when I am trying to compile it via manual method as `java main.java` This thing is working for me but not working automatically by just clicking on run button on vs code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following configuration in the **setting.json** file to specify the `jdk` path

```json
    "java.configuration.runtimes": [
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-1.8",
            "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Eclipse Adoptium\\jdk-8.0.332.9-hotspot"
        },
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-17",
            "path": "C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Eclipse Adoptium\\jdk-17.0.3.7-hotspot",
            "default": true
        }
    ],
```

Or use this configuration to specify the folder path of the JDK (17 or newer) used to start the Java language server.

```json
    "java.jdt.ls.java.home": "c:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Eclipse Adoptium\\jdk-17.0.3.7-hotspot",
```

*The above configuration is an example, please modify it according to your own situation.*

Answer (score 0):

On any Linux/Android device you can use next command from termux session:

```
Java -XshowSettings
```

and get path like this:

java.home=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/opt/openjdk.

After that, edit

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

and append to the end:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/opt/openjdk

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Exit Termux and run it again to apply JAVA_HOME

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).